# Filtering by value calculated in instance method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `House` model that has a `price` attribute which is calculated using an instance method.

Let's say that the price is constantly changing due to market rates, inflation, etc. Thus we need a `price_today` method to get the current price.

How can I create a named scope (or something) to filter the houses using a maximum price and minimum price?

I tried doing something like this, but I feel it's a little hacky...

```
  def index
    @houses = # get houses from DB

    if not params[:max_price].nil?
      @houses.keep_if { |h|  h.price_today <= params[:max_price].to_f }
    end

    if not params[:min_price].nil?
      @houses.keep_if { |h| h.price_today >= params[:min_price].to_f }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A named scope (or a `where` clause) would definitely be faster that querying and filtering the instantiated objects.
However, I'm afraid that if `price_today` does not exist in the DB you won't be able to use them.

You can improve your code, though.
The conditions can be made simpler, and you can use a single call to `keep_if`.

```
max = params[:max_price].presence
min = params[:min_price].presence

if max || min
  @houses.keep_if do |house|
    a = max ? (house.price_today <= max.to_f) : true
    b = min ? (house.price_today >= min.to_f) : true
    a && b
  end
end
```

If you want, instead of `keep_if` you can use [`select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-select).

Comment: It's too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Another variation:

```
{ max_price: ->(price, max) { price <= max },
  min_price: ->(price, min) { price >= min } }.each { |prop, cond|
    @houses.select! { |h| cond.(h.price_today, params[prop].to_f) } unless params[prop].nil?
}
```

In case of lambda for particular property you can easily add another conditions=)